# Unmanaged dll in C#.net having entrypoint error

Tags: c#

I have a dll called OMGICardDll.dll that communicate with a usb plugin Smartcard device to read the data from card

Here is the code That I Used :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("OMGICardDll",EntryPoint="ReadName",ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,SetLastError=false)]
   public  static extern string ReadName();
  //Form1 fm = new Form1();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      txtName.Text = ReadName();
  }


}
```

When I clicked save button I found System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Comment: Only use ExactSpelling if you know what you are doing, use dumpbin.exe /exports to find the real name.  You cannot pinvoke this function as-is, it will crash when the pinvoke marshaller tries to release the returned string.  The return type must be IntPtr, Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to convert.

Answer (score 1):

The error may indicate that `OMGICardDll.dll` could be found and loaded, but that the function `ReadName` does not exist in it or is not exported from it.

Can you verify that the routine is spelled precisely like that?  And is exported?  (And isn't actually called `ReadNameA` or `ReadNameW`?)